# Extracting nodeId from Selenium WebDriver for Chrome Remote Interface

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-remote-debugging

I was able to invoke Chrome Remote Interface functions inside Selenium WebDriver session (Page.captureScreenshot, Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride etc). But I have problem with invoking methods which work on DOM element. The problem is with nodeId parameter. For example this function https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-setFileInputFiles accepts as one of parameters nodeId. I can't figure out how to extract nodeId based on IWebElement (or RemoteWebElement) from SeleniumWebdriver.

How can I find nodeId using Selenium or Javascript?

More info about Chrome Remote Interface could be found here https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer asking on devtools-protocol issue tracker here https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/66

The full working solution could be found here:
https://github.com/cezarypiatek/Tellurium/blob/master/Src/MvcPages/SeleniumUtils/ChromeRemoteInterface/ChromeRemoteInterface.cs

```
private long GetChromeNodeId(IWebElement inputElement)
{
    driver.ExecuteScript(@"(function(fileInput){
        window.__tellurium_chromerinode = fileInput;
    })(arguments[0])", inputElement);


    var evaluateResponse = SendCommand("Runtime.evaluate", new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["expression"] = "window.__tellurium_chromerinode"
    });

    driver.ExecuteScript(@"(function(fileInput){
        delete window.__tellurium_chromerinode;
    })()");

    var remoteObjectId = evaluateResponse.GetValue<string>("result.objectId");

    var rquestNodeResponse = SendCommand("DOM.requestNode", new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["objectId"] = remoteObjectId
    });

    return rquestNodeResponse.GetValue<long>("nodeId");
}
```